# scenarios of using oauth2 vs your own token

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

If you are an API developer, when would you go for OAuth2 instead of a simple scheme where you just send some API key in the header (JWT or other)? Is OAuth2 still relevant if you don't need access to third-party APIs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually "send some API key in the header (JWT or other)" is what OAuth 2.0 specifies in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2. Let's call that the 2nd leg, which is trivial like your proposal, but standardized.

**Obtaining** the API key - i.e. the 1st leg - is where the perceived complexity in OAuth 2.0 comes from, using so called grant types. Yet you don't *have* to use an OAuth 2.0 grant type in your Client to obtain an access token. You're also free to just configure an `access_token` in your Client like you'd do with a traditional API key. (it still begs the question how you'd generate the access token just like how you'd generate an API key)